# Windows black screen while trying to boot up windows installed with Kali Linux

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, kali-linux

I'm encountering a issue while dual booting Windows and Kali in my MacBook Air (Late 2017 model). I have both Windows 11 and Kali Linux on my laptop. I installed Windows 11 initially, and than Kali Linux. After successful Kali Linux installation, I am not able to boot into Windows and a blank screen shows up when trying to boot into Windows.

When I try to click the Windows Boot Manager option in the Kali boot menu, it just show a blank box with no options or information to do anything further. I've tried to install windows and Kali approx. 5-6 times within the last 6 months with both windows 10 & 11, and each time, I've encountered the exact same problem.

I used to install and run windows and Kali together on this laptop by this exact process but suddenly things are not working.

Please also keep in mind few points:

1. I am reasonably certain that I haven't formatted the Windows partition. However, I'm not entirely confident about the small partition that Windows typically creates during its installation process.
2. I've already attempted to run the "sudo update-grub" command. Unfortunately, this hasn't yielded any positive results.
3. During the installation of Kali Linux, there were no errors or warnings – everything appeared to proceed without any hitches.
4. No data of windows partition is deleted in this entire process.
5. I have also tried dual booting windows with Ubuntu. Everything work well when I install Ubuntu and both Ubuntu and windows boot up very well. Thus problem seems to be with Kali.
6. Before some months I used to run 3 OS in this Laptop together - Windows 11, Kali Linux & MacOS.

I am attaching some screenshots and a video which shows what I am encountering while trying to boot into windows: firstly, by clicking on the Windows Boot Manager within the Kali boot menu, and secondly, by opting for Windows from the device boot menu.

I am guessing that Kali installation is messing up with windows partition and windows is not recognizing the boot drive content

I'm hopeful that the community's expertise can can help on what's causing this problem and how it can be resolved. Please let me know if you want any other information. Thank you all in advance for your help!

1. Trying to boot into windows from Kali boot Menu.

a. [Kali Boot Menu Image] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0dxt.jpg

b. [After Clicking Windows boot Manager blank box shows up] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU3cu.jpg

2. Trying to boot into windows with Device boot Menu.

a. [Laptop boot menu.] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/97pm3.jpg

b. [After selecting partition where windows is installed it just keep showing blank screen instead of booting into Windows. Earlier when things used to work windows used to boot up after selecting this option.] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/z582i.jpg

3. Video of whole process if it can help - https://streamable.com/8w6kdz

Comment: You need to disable secure boot to run Kali 2023 or earlier..  Your machine is too old to run production Windows 11, so you must be using Windows Insider or set the flag (registry) to ignore Windows 11 requirements.

Comment: Yes, I made a bootable pendrive of windows 11 with Rufus which at start give option to bypass TPM & all other requirements. How can those things cause problem be cause before installing Kali LInux WIndows 11 was booting up fine.

As you said i'll try to disable secure boot and will update you with the results. Also like I said I used to use both OS together before some months and never disabled secure boot still things used to work great. I don't know what I am doing wrong this time. Thank You for your reply.